# How can I consolidate results onto one line

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I have a query that I'm trying to consolidate onto 1 line using SQL server.
It keeps forcing me to group by the `Frequency` column but I only want to group by the `UserId`.  Can anyone let me know what I'm doing wrong.

CODE:

```
SELECT userid, frequency,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 1) AS Onetime,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 2) AS Daily,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 3) AS Weekly,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 4) AS Fortnightly,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 5) AS Monthly,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 6) AS Quarterly,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 7) AS SemiAnnual,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 8) AS Annual
FROM AppTasks
where userid = 'userid@gmail.com'
group by UserID, Frequency
```

Data:

[image]

Comment: You have to remove the projection of the `frequency` column in your select. And then you can safely remove the `frequency` column in your group by.

Comment: Just take `frequency` out of your `SELECT` and also from the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: So that was the first thing i tried and it produced this error message: Column 'AppTasks.Frequency' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you try this?

```
SELECT userid,
SUM(CASE WHEN frequency = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Onetime,
SUM(CASE WHEN frequency = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Daily,
SUM(CASE WHEN frequency = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Weekly,
SUM(CASE WHEN frequency = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Fortnightly,
SUM(CASE WHEN frequency = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Monthly,
SUM(CASE WHEN frequency = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Quarterly,
SUM(CASE WHEN frequency = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS SemiAnnual,
FROM AppTasks
where userid = 'userid@gmail.com'
group by UserID;
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you so much. I understand your query, do you know why mine was not working.

Comment: @FuriousD Yes. You need to preserve the `frequency` column in the grouping because otherwise you are getting an error, that it is part not part of grouping or aggregation. But, when you have this column in the result set, you are not allowed to pivot the data as the `userid` - `frequency`  combination is unique.

Answer (score 1):

The original query isn't working because the SELECT statement contains 7 subqueries, each one counting *all* records with frequencies returned by the outer query, not just the user's.

You can use [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) to calculate the counts for specific frequency numbers and display them as columns:

```
declare @apptasks table (userid nvarchar(20),frequency int)

insert into @apptasks
values
('userid@gmail.com',1),
('userid@gmail.com',2),
('userid@gmail.com',3),
('userid@gmail.com',4),
('userid@gmail.com',5),
('userid@gmail.com',6),
('userid@gmail.com',7),
('userid@gmail.com',7),
('userid@gmail.com',2),
('userid@gmail.com',1),
('userid@gmail.com',1)


select 
    userid, 
    [1] AS Onetime,
    [2] AS Daily,
    [3] AS Weekly,
    [4] AS Fortnightly,
    [5] AS Monthly,
    [6] AS Quarterly,
    [7] AS SemiAnnual
from ( select 
              userid,
              frequency 
       from @apptasks) as source
PIVOT (
    count(frequency) for Frequency in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7])
) as pvt
```

The result is

```
userid            Onetime   Daily   Weekly  Fortnightly Monthly Quarterly   SemiAnnual
userid@gmail.com  3         2       1       1           1       1           2
```

PIVOT and UNPIVOT work if you know which values you want to use beforehand. PIVOT essentially calculates the aggregate (COUNT(*)) for the field (Frequency) values in the `IN` clause and returns them as columns named after the values.

You can omit Frequency values too :

```
select 
    userid, 
    [1] AS Onetime,
    [2] AS Daily,
    [3] AS Weekly,
    [4] AS Fortnightly,
    [5] AS Monthly
from (select userid,frequency from @apptasks) as source
PIVOT 
(
        count(frequency) for Frequency in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])
) as pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

simply since you want group by `userID` only , so remove `frequency` from Select statment as next:-

```
SELECT userid,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 1) AS Onetime,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 2) AS Daily,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 3) AS Weekly,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 4) AS Fortnightly,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 5) AS Monthly,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 6) AS Quarterly,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 7) AS SemiAnnual,
(select count(frequency) where frequency = 8) AS Annual
FROM AppTasks
where userid = 'userid@gmail.com'
group by UserID
```

Comment: So that was the first thing i tried and it produced this error message: Column 'AppTasks.Frequency' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Even if this worked it would have the same problem as the original. It counts *all* rows with the specified frequency, not just the user's